# What is the -v switch in go get -u -v

Tags: go, documentation, go-get

According to [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them)

> Usage:
>
> `go get [-d] [-t] [-u] [-v] [build flags] [packages]`

The text explain every switch, but `-v` is missing from docs.

`go help get` also doesn't mention `-v`, although it is clearly present in usage:

```
$ go help get 
usage: go get [-d] [-t] [-u] [-v] [-insecure] [build flags] [packages]
```

What is this switch for?

Comment: _Is_ it missing? I could find _"print the names of packages as they are compiled"_ on that page.

Comment: It is because you have missed a paragraph. https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies `The build flags are shared by the build, clean, get, install, list, run, and test commands:`

Comment: So why `go help get` and doc shows "-v" as it was apart from [build flags] ?
I don't know why the question is being down voted, is that so bad? :(

Comment: never mind and try again, the crowd is always happy to vote, up or down. the crowd can be wrong too. really bad question are closed or deleted. if you post too much bad question, you will get banned, you are lucky if that is your only problem in life... though this question is not very interesting from a programming POV. this surely is just some glitches in the doc for good reasons we dont understand from that far away of the duty to write and maintain it. consider to rise an issue and help fixing it in https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/cmd/go/alldocs.go

Comment: *"the build flags are shared by..."* - this explains everything, but people who downvoted don't seem to know about this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/get) :

> The -v flag enables verbose progress and debug output.

Get also accepts build flags to control the installation. See `go help build`.

For more about specifying packages, see `go help packages`.

For more about how 'go get' finds source code to
download, see `go help importpath`.